# Sprites misaligned with bodies, can't find bug in the display loop

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, box2d, box2dweb

I'm currently creating a game with box2Dweb. Whenever my shapes move toward the bottom-right corner of the canvas, their sprite seems to move with some offset that grows bigger and bigger (and if I move the shape toward the top left corner of the canvas, the sprite aligns better and better), and I really can't see why. Do you guys see something wrong on my display loop ?

I'm creating square cubes with this snippet:

```
this.createSquare= function(x, y, bodyDef, fixtureDef, object){
    if(object.isStatic){
        bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_staticBody;
    }else{
        bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
    }
    fixtureDef.shape = new object.shape;
    polygonShape = fixtureDef.shape;
    polygonShape.SetAsBox(object.width,object.height);
    bodyDef.position.Set(x/game.worldScale,y/game.worldScale);
}
```

And I use this function in my display loop to display some sprites on it:

```
for(var i=0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        context.save();
        console.log(context);
        context.translate(tab[i].GetBody().GetPosition().x * 30, tab[i].GetBody().GetPosition().y * 30);
        context.rotate(tab[i].GetBody().GetAngle());
            var dataResize = { 'image'    : tab[i].GetUserData().img,
                               'imgPosX'  : tab[i].GetBody().GetPosition().x,
                               'imgPosY'  : tab[i].GetBody().GetPosition().y,
                               'imgWidth' : tab[i].m_shape.m_vertices[2].x*60,
                               'imgHeight': tab[i].m_shape.m_vertices[2].y*60
            }
            context.drawImage(
                        dataResize.image, 
                        (dataResize.imgPosX) - (dataResize.imgWidth/2), //img pos x
                        (dataResize.imgPosY) - (dataResize.imgHeight/2), //img pos y
                        dataResize.imgWidth, //img wdith
                        dataResize.imgHeight //img height
                    )
        context.restore();
    }
```

What am I missing ? I've tried reading pretty much everything I could find on SOFLOW and couldn't see the issue.

Thanks

Comment: When you say 'aligns', what are you checking the alignment of the sprite with? It seems very strange to use the body GetPosition value twice (once for context.translate, and once for imgPosX/imgPosY).

Comment: Yeah, the loop is not really optimized, so far... Thanks for the input though.

Comment: It's not a question of optimization. Applying the position twice will make the image twice as far from the origin as it should be.

Comment: Nah, it's not an issue at all, not what was at the root of the problem !

Comment: lol really... in your own answer below, you have removed the second usage of the position.

Comment: Oh yeah, you were right, I think I read your comment too fast, my bad !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found what was wrong:

In the drawImage I did

```
(dataResize.imgPosX) - (dataResize.imgWidth/2), //img pos x
(dataResize.imgPosY) - (dataResize.imgHeight/2), //img pos y
```

When I was supposed to do

```
(-dataResize.imgWidth/2)
```

instead !